# Determine if the set of all eventually zero sequences is $G_\delta $ in $\ell_2$

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, baire-category

For the normed space $\left(\ell^ 2 , \|\cdot\|_2\right) $

I need to check if the following set is of type $ G_\delta $ , $F_\sigma$ :

$$E = \left\{ x \in \ell^2 : \mbox{ there exists } N \ge1 \mbox{ s.t } x_n = 0 \mbox{ for each } n \ge N  \right\}.$$

I managed to prove that this set is $F_\sigma$.

I think it is not $G_\delta $ but im not sure how to prove it.

Thanks for helping

Comment: It is dense in $\ell^2$. What does Baire say then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Completely revised and corrected HINT:** Let $G=\ell^2\setminus E$. $E$ is an $F_\sigma$, so $G$ is a $G_\delta$. Thus, there are open sets $G_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $G=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}G_n$.

- Show that $G$ is dense in $\ell^2$, and conclude that each $G_n$ is dense in $\ell^2$.

Suppose that $E$ is also a $G_\delta$. Then there are open sets $U_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $E=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$.

- Show that $E$ is dense in $\ell^2$, and conclude that each $U_n$ is dense in $\ell^2$.
- Use the fact that $\{G_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a countable family of dense open sets in the complete metric space $\ell^2$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: What if $\epsilon_n=1/n $? Then we have $\cap_nB(z,1/n)=\{z\}$.

Comment: @user254665: No, we don’t; that’s the whole point. The sequence $\left\langle\frac1{(n+1)^2}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$ is in $B\left(z,\frac1n\right)$, for instance.

Comment: @Liad: Almost: it’s in the intersection **if it’s in** $\ell^2$. You could take the $n$-th term to be $\min\left\{\frac1{2\epsilon_n},\frac1n\right\}$, for instance.

Comment: @Liad: Yes, it should; clearly I’m not quite awake yet, to let that slip by!

Comment: @Liad: You’re welcome!

Comment: @Liad: Sorry: I really was still a bit asleep. We do have to work a little harder than that. Give me a few minutes; I’m right in the middle of something, but I’ll get back to you shortly.

Comment: @Liad: Finished quicker than I thought. I also realized that I was thinking of a completely different topology on the sequence space when I wrote my answer. The answer is nonsense. If you would remove your acceptance, I can delete the answer for now while I think about it again (in the *right* topology this time!).

Comment: @Liad: I’ve completely revised the answer; the argument is actually easier than the one that I originally had in mind (for the wrong topology).